# How to load related entities in Jetbrain's Exposed DSL approach

Tags: jetbrains-ide, kotlin-exposed

How to load related entities in Jetbrain's Exposed using DSL approach?

For example: - I am having entity "User" and now I want to load its "Role" details along with every user row whenever I hit select query on it.

Comment: Do you read that section of a wiki https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#eager-loading ?

Comment: Yes, I read it but it talks about "DAO" specific. I want it in DSL.

Comment: When you use DSL you should work with rows and there are no helpers to load _more_ data in a row as you have to map to your data manually. It means what if you want to load users with all roles you have to make `leftJoin` with both tables and then make `groupBy` in your code like: `User.leftJoin(Role).selectAll().map { UserDao.fromRow(it) to RoleDao.fromRow(it) }.groupBy(it.first)`. Or maybe I didn't understand your problem

Comment: I want the exact implementation of eager loading which you suggest in first link using DAO. So problem is very simeple I want DAO equivalent code in DSL for eager loading.

Comment: There is no such functionality as there is nothing to load eagerly. DSL works just like an SQL and always returns ResultRows. How would you expect it to work? Could you provide a simple code?